# matlab - how to form output of matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have used the following commands

```
Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID=[Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID;[PB_ID,time]]; 
Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID2 = vec2mat(Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID,10,4);
Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID2(Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID2==0)=[];



       1        1610           2        1615           3        1620           4        1625           5        1630
       6        1635           7        1640           8        1645           9        1650          10        1655
      11        1660          12        1665          13        1670          14        1675          15        1680
      16        1685          17        1690          18        1695          19        1700          20        1705
```

this is the result i get, but is there anyway that i can get the results in an order:

```
1 1610    6 1635     11 1660
2 1615    7 1640      12 1665
```

and so on...? I mean somehow sorted

Comment: Are you simply just looking to take the transpose of the output matrix?

Comment: somehow like that. the transpose but, by 2 elements

Comment: You can sort the output with this one-liner `reshape(union(a(:,1:2:end)' , a(:,2:2:end)','rows'), 5, [])` where `a` is `Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID2`.

Answer (score 1):

A small detour via a 3d matrix helps. The input after the first line is probably:
`Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID=[[1:20].',[1610:5:1705].']`

1) Reshape so that 1:5 can be found together in one row (regardless at which dimension)
`y=reshape(Arrival_A_PB_VS_PB_ID,5,4,2)`

2) You want a 4x10 matrix. Reshape to the intended size and previously permute the data so everything ends up where it should.
`z=reshape(permute(y,[2,3,1]),4,10)`